# Compute $F_V(t)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Given $f_{X,Y}(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{rcl} 1/2& x\in(-1,0],-1-x\leq y\leq1+x\\1/2& x\in(0,1),x-1\leq y\leq1-x\end{array}\right.$
> Compute $F_V(t)$ V=X-Y

I've tried using $F_V(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{t}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x+y,y)dydx$ and got $F_V(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{rcl} \frac{t^2+2t+2}{2}& t\leq0\\
\frac{-t^2+2t+2}{2}& t\geq0\end{array}\right.$
But in the answers the result is $V\sim U(-1,1)$

Comment: [Probability theory](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_theory) is [about the measure-theoretic foundations](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8587/290189) of stochastics.  The tag ([tag:probability-theory]) should be used for questions concerning this subject, not for questions about calculating a specific probability.  Use ([tag:probability]) instead, see also [meta](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1686/290189).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that the region in which $f_{X,Y}$ is non-zero is a square $\huge\diamond$ with vertices $(\pm1, \pm1)$ and $(\pm1, \mp1)$. i.e. $(X, Y) \sim U\left({\huge \diamond}\right)$ since the value of this given pdf is $1/2$ on the square.

Rewrite the inequalities

\begin{cases}
x \in (-1,0], & -1-x \le y \le 1 + x &\implies x - y \ge -1, x + y \ge -1 \\
x \in (0,1), & x-1 \le y \le 1 - x &\implies x - y \le 1, x + y \le 1
\end{cases}

Introduce the auxiliary variable $W = X+Y$, and do something similar for variables in small letters.  It's clear that the pdf $f_{V,W}$ is $1/4$ on $[-1,1] \times [-1,1]$, from which it's clear that $V \sim U([-1,1])$.

Comment: Thanks it is really a nice way to look at this :)